# UI elements - make position fluid?

Tags: iphone, uiview

I realise you can make dimentions fluid by using the autoresizing mask to give a flexible width/height.

What about making a position fluid?

For instance if I set the centre of a UIButton at `self.view.frame.size.width/2` how can I make it reposition if the view changes size?

Thanks
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the button's `autoresizingMask` to `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin`.

Comment: ok, will this work though if the button's at `self.view.frame.size.width/4` or `(self.view.frame.size.width/4)*3`?

Comment: this has very random effects when used to reposition elements during rotation... any idea what could be causing this?